# Is there a way to pull information from one variable created inside a function, and use it in another

Tags: c#, function

I was wondering if there is a way I can take the information that gets passed through EleWeight in this function I created below, and use that information in another function.

```
static void ElementData(string EleName, string EleSymbol, string EleNumber, string EleWeight)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Element: " + EleName);
        Console.WriteLine("Symbol: " + EleSymbol);
        Console.WriteLine("Atomic Number: " + EleNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Atomic Weight: " + EleWeight);
        NewElement();
    }
```

Comment: I would say a global variable would do fine, but are you using EleWeight in the function "NewElement"? If so, pass that through?

Comment: You have to put it somewhere... A `static` field for example... Note that this will break if there is no clear ordering between `ElementData()` calls and `OtherFunction()` calls. The suggested way of doing it is probably calling `OtherFunction()` from `ElementData()`

Comment: @code4life That's not appropriate.

Comment: @Rawling: If that is the case, I would also argue that arbitrarily -1'ing posts is inappropriate as well, IMHO. At the very least, provide a helpful comment, to help improve content quality, etc. Otherwise we'll end up with a site full of -1'ed posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void NewElement(string EleWeight)
{
    ...
}

static void ElementData(string EleName, string EleSymbol, string EleNumber, string EleWeight)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Element: " + EleName);
    Console.WriteLine("Symbol: " + EleSymbol);
    Console.WriteLine("Atomic Number: " + EleNumber);
    Console.WriteLine("Atomic Weight: " + EleWeight);
    NewElement(EleWeight);
}
```

If you want to keep the information between function calls you would need to store that in some kind of class field variable

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it somewhere... A static field for example... Note that this will break if there is no clear ordering between `ElementData()` calls and `OtherFunction()` calls. The suggested way of doing it is probably calling `OtherFunction()` from `ElementData()`

Another way:

```
public class OtherFunctionClass
{
    public readonly int EleWeight;
    public OtherFunctionClass(int eleWeight) 
    {
        EleWeight = eleWeight;
    }

    public void OtherFunction()
    {
    }
}
```

and then from `ElementData`:

```
static OtherFunctionClass ElementData(string EleName, string EleSymbol, string EleNumber, string EleWeight)
{
    ....
    ....
    return new OtherFunctionClass(EleWeight);
}
```

So `ElementData` returns an object that contains the `EleWeight` and that has the `OtherFunction` method.